# How to mock a service in angular?(With comparing response)

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, angular2-services

I have a service form which returns an object and username in it will be bound in my template and I am trying to write a test case for it.

I tried the following

```js
      beforeEach(() => {
         shallow = new Shallow(AreaInterestsComponent, OverviewLandingPageModule)
        .dontMock(HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG)
        .mock(UserStateService, {
      getUserState: () => userState
      });

     });
    it('Check if admin role is not selected', async () => {
        const { instance, find, fixture } = await shallow.render({});
        // Trying to test my service here
        const username  = find('.username-class');
        expect(username.length).toBe(1);
    });
```

Here I want to pass the response as an input like below

```
await shallow.render({userData});
```

Here I want to pass data to my service and check the value length in tag but not sure how to mock my 'userSvc'.

Comment: Are you using TestBed.configure({})? Could you show more of the testbed code and I could should you how to mock, you need to use a spy, but if i could see how you configure the testbed it would be better

Comment: @Joey Gough,added.

Comment: I am using shallow

Comment: can you please help me.......

Comment: what is `AreaInterestsComponent` and how is `userData` passed into the component? Is it fetched from a service, or is it passed as an `@Input()`?

Comment: fetched from service

Comment: you need to call the appropiate method, e.g. `instance.getUserState()` then I guess you should call the mock

Comment: can you please help me with full code.

Comment: what exactly does your `.unmock()` and `mock()` method do in your shallow object?

Comment: I would use the Testbed for this kind of testing. Can you show your full component and service?